# Mobile network does not work after flashing a custom ROM on Samsung Galaxy J7

Tags: samsung, custom-roms, mobile-network, imei

I've flashed Lineage OS 18.1, 17.1, and Havoc OS to Samsung Galaxy J7, but it seems that every custom ROM I flash on my mobile changes my IMEI to 350000000000006, thus my mobile network doesn't work. WiFi still works properly.

I've tried:

- Formatting the device with TWRP first, instead of just wiping.
- Installing the recovery of the Lineage OS 18.1 itself and making things by it.
- The MTK tool to repair my IMEI, but my mobile is not MediaTek-based, so it doesn't work.
- A bunch of apps that promise to repair your IMEI, but no success.
- Fastboot, but it seems that this mobile does not support it.

Specs:

- My mobile: SM-J700M
- Brand: Samsung
- OS: Lineage 18.1
- Country: Brazil
- Country code: 55
- Mobile service provider: TIM

Any clue on how I proceed after this?

Comment: For certain Samsung devices it is necessary to backup one of the partitions before installing a custom ROM and afterwards restore this partition to retain mobile network/IMEI functionality. Not sure if this is also required for your phone model.

Comment: @Robert explain better, please. By official version (that works mobile network) i have just the android 6. Should i install android 6 and make a backup and recovery in lineage 18.1 ?

Comment: I am not sure if the situation is the same for your device, therefore I postet it as comment. I had once a Samsung device that had large warnings in the tutorial for installing a custom ROM that first you need to take a backup of a special partition (don't remember it's name) that is otherwise lost. Without that partition cellular does no longer work (IMEI invalid). Once the partition is lost it is very difficult to reconstruct or finding an alternative version that works because that partition is device specific and thus not included in any official system firmware package.